# How can I access my plist in another viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I have one 3 arrays that i am trying to save to 3 different plists in one view and then load that data into an array in another view. I am having trouble figuring out how to access the data in the plist in my other view and save it correctly in my initial view. Here is the code from my first view.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *documentsDirectory1 = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString *documentsDirectory2 = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:2];
    NSString *documentsDirectory3 = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:3];
    NSString *documentPlistPath1 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"balance.plist"];
    NSString *documentsPlistPath2 = [documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"principal.plist"];
    NSString *documentsPlistPath3 = [documentsDirectory2 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"interest.plist"];
    NSString *documentsPlistpath4 = [documentsDirectory3 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dates.plist"];
    [dateValues writeToFile:documentsPlistpath4 atomically:YES];
    [balanceLabels writeToFile:documentPlistPath1 atomically:YES];

    [pricipalLabels writeToFile:documentsPlistPath2 atomically:YES];
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Send a notification via NSNotificationCenter to the other view controller to save. Alternatively you can get a mutable copy of the plist as shown in @almas's answer, modify it, and write the updates to disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create an array

```
NSArray *array = @[@"abc", @"cba"];
```

get path to plist file

```
NSString *documentsFolderPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileName = @"my_plist_file";
NSString *filePath = [documentsFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
```

save an array to .plist

```
[array writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

read an array from .plist

```
NSArray *arrayFromDisk = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Comment: if I try and put NSArray = *arrayFromDisk = [NSArray arrayWithContentsofFile: filePath]; it is saying filePath use of undeclared identifier

Comment: I am trying to load the array in another viewcontroller so it doesnt have access to filePath string

Comment: @mnka you need to initialize the same filePath string in your other view controller, just like you it when you save the array to the disk, just copy this code   NSString *documentsFolderPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileName = @"my_plist_file";
NSString *filePath = [documentsFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

Comment: array is coming back (null)

Comment: i tried different test arrays and none are saving, do I have to physically add a plist file to my project?